# Liferay REST Template with certificate

Tags: java, jax-rs, liferay, liferay-7

I am using Liferay 7 and need to build a REST API with the REST Template which is using JAX-RS. Now I need to add a client certificate in a .p12 file. I looked around a bit on how to do that but I am stuck as all the examples I found are only snippets.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Follow this link https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/jax-rs

Comment: I don't see how this link helps me. This tutorial talks about OAuth, I need to use a self signed certificate

Comment: OAuth is basically authentication of user, if you taking about SSL certificated which is basically protect application data when it travel in the network so both are different.

Comment: Could you elaborate your description ? What kind of template are you using ? the blade example, maven archetype ,, etc,,, next step ... as i understand so far , your want to secure your api via https, which is mainly directing to the server config and the application path you want to secure .. which server are you using ?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. I am using the REST Template from blade. I don't understand the question about the server

Comment: Did you try adding the certificate to the java cacerts?

Comment: No. But I need to do this outside of Liferay, right?

Comment: What do you want the client certificate for? If you can elaborate a bit more your question maybe we can help you better.